# How should I file a bug about Ubiquity?

Tags: ubiquity

What is the best channel for making suggestions for changes to Ubuntu (or, more specifically, Ubiquity)? I have spotted an issue that is not really a bug, but its a fairly big usability hurdle.

I was helping somebody to install Ubuntu on a virtual machine, and they kept getting stuck at the ‘Who are you?’ section. Eventually, I spotted that they had an uppercase letter in their username.

The problem is that the installer did not let them know that this was the issue, and it was very frustrating for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely [seeing this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/555896).

To better answer your question, most teams in Ubuntu have a [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/) where you can contact a team if you have recommendations. In your specific example the [ubuntu-installer](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-installer) team is who you're looking for.

As you can see the issue has already been reported (and fixed in the next version!) so I recommend doing a search for your issue first to ensure you're not duplicating a bug or something someone else has already brought up.

If you have some kind of grand visionary dream of an idea that should be implemented then as donatello suggests, [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com) is the right place. The Ubuntu Technical Board will now be [providing responses](http://mdzlog.alcor.net/2010/11/03/weathering-the-ubuntu-brainstorm/) to ideas there.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing does seem to be a bug because the software should let them know that uppercase letters are not allowed. Here is the bug tracker for Ubiquity: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubiquity - please report the bug there.

Also, to make general suggestions about Ubuntu, you can make them at Ubuntu Brainstorm (http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) where the community will help vote up the best ideas for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions, change and improvement proposals can be registered in [Launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/).
They are called Blueprints.