# Need new feature when browsing installed apps

Tags: unity

When we browse installed apps, we need on right clik on app, information on the selected apps, possibility to initiate uninstall for the selected apps.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the question?

For suggestions see this:

[how to make suggestion for ubuntu improvements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14017/how-to-make-suggestions-for-ubuntu-improvements)